# Undefined index because of AJAX or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, leaflet

I'm trying to send data to php by ajax but this don't work. Here is the code :

index.php (code in html)

```
                   
<form action="" id="LoopPosition" class="myPosition" method="post">
     <span>Longitude :</span> <input id="displayLong" name="displayLong" type="text" style="width: 400px;"> <br>
     <span>Latitude: </span> <input id="displayLat" name="displayLat" type="text" style="width: 400px;"> <br>
     <span>Accuracy : </span> <input id="displayAccu" name="displayAccu" type="text" style="width: 400px;"> <br>
          <?php if (isset($_GET['DeliveryCourse'])) : ?>
     <button type="submit" name="submitPositionForLivreur" class="btn btn-info" id="clicAuto">Clic to send</button>
          <?php endif; ?>
                            
</form>
```

ajaxPostToDatabase.js (inside of index.php)

```
            $("#LoopPosition").submit(function(e) {
                const lng_forAjax = $("#displayLong").val();
                const lat_forAjax = $("#displayLat").val();
                const accuracy_forAjax = $("#displayAccu").val();


                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'updateLivePosition.php',
                    data: {
                        'lng_forAjax': lng_forAjax,
                        'lat_forAjax': lat_forAjax,
                        'accuracy_forAjax': accuracy_forAjax

                    },
                    success: function(msg) {
                        var msg = lng_forAjax + " " + lat_forAjax;
                        alert(msg);
                    },

                });
            })
```

updateLivePosition.php

```
<?php

        if(isset($_POST['submitPositionForLivreur'])){
            echo $_POST['lng_forAjax']." ".$_POST['lat_forAjax']." ". $_POST['accuracy_forAjax'];
        } 
    }
```

With all of that, i still get an Undefined index : lng_forAjax; Undefined index : lat_forAjax; Undefined index : accuracy_forAjax

Comment: Where is `ToTheDatabase.php` used? or is that really named `updateLivePosition.php`?

Comment: Yes ToTheDatabase.php = updateLivePosition.php . I renamed here for the platform in order to for you to better understand

Comment: The PHP you've posted shouldnt do anything in that case as `submitPositionForLivreur` is not sent in your AJAX request.

Comment: (If altering code in the future for here be sure you change everything. You missed the ajax call which means the code blocks have no relation)

Comment: i modified and i think the code is more clear for all of you now. Thanks !

Comment: Your `data: {}` and `if(isset($_POST['submitPositionForLivreur'])){` are the real code you have? If so this shouldn't throw the notices you're reporting. It should skip the whole code block because that index is not set.

Comment: @user3783243 yes, it's the real code. Really

Comment: `<form action=""` is also correct or set to `updateLivePosition.php`?

Comment: no. my form isnt set to `<form action="updateLivePosition.php"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your **submitPositionForLivreur** in your Ajax data and set it to true. By doing this, you're essentially mimicking the behavior of a traditional form submission.

```js
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'updateLivePosition.php',
    data: {
        'lng_forAjax': lng_forAjax,
        'lat_forAjax': lat_forAjax,
        'accuracy_forAjax': accuracy_forAjax,
        'submitPositionForLivreur': true  // Add this line
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        var msg = lng_forAjax + " " + lat_forAjax;
        alert(msg);
    },
});
```

In your PHP file, you can then check for the existence of **$_POST['submitPositionForLivreur']**

```php
if(isset($_POST['submitPositionForLivreur'])){
    echo $_POST['lng_forAjax']." ".$_POST['lat_forAjax']." ". $_POST['accuracy_forAjax'];
}
```

And make sure to prevent the default form submission in your jQuery submit event handler

```js
$("#LoopPosition").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // Add this line

    ......
});
```

Comment: How would that produce the reported notices? The `isset($_POST['submitPositionForLivreur'])` is never met so the code inside is never called.

Comment: ... or the real answer here is the third block of code and OP just needs `preventDefault` because the form submission has different input names? The form doesnt submit to `updateLivePosition.php` though so I don't think that is the case

Comment: The "Undefined index" notices aren't due to `isset($_POST['submitPositionForLivreur'])`, but because the PHP script tries to access `$_POST['lng_forAjax']`, `$_POST['lat_forAjax']`, and `$_POST['accuracy_forAjax']` without verifying their existence. If these notices appear, it indicates that these values aren't being received by the server, possibly due to issues with the AJAX request, server-side script, or network.

Comment: @FadiChamoun I tried your solution. Now I'm not having an undefined index issues but my code can't "echo" my $_POST and others...

Comment: With the `isset` that code won't be fired, that's the purpose of `isset` it checks if the code index is set. If not set code inside isn't executed.  See https://3v4l.org/U8OD3, so unless `submitPositionForLivreur` is already in `data` this can't be solution

Comment: Yes, thats why I added `submitPositionForLivreur` into the data and set it to true.

Comment: @susanoov90 You are not seeing the echo message because you are inside the html page. The php file recieves the ajax data but you need to do something with it inside the php file. Like sending it to the database or store it into a txt file somewhere. For example: `$message = $_POST['lng_forAjax']." ".$_POST['lat_forAjax']." ". $_POST['accuracy_forAjax']; file_put_contents('test.txt', $message); `

Comment: @FadiChamoun They have `success: function(msg) {...` so there should be an alert that sends back what the PHP outputs.. I presume currently that alert had the undefined notices in it

Comment: @FadiChamoun i tried your solution. It doenst work unfortunately...

Comment: @user3783243 my `alert(msg)` in the ajax code clearly echo my values.

Comment: @susanoov90 Oh, just noticed you overwrite `msg` in the success function call. The `msg` in `function(msg)` would be what the PHP returned. It is unclear what issue you are having if you dont need/want the return from the PHP script.